# Appending text to end of a textfile

Tags: command-line

How can I append a new line to a text file followed by current date and time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
echo "text" >> file
date >> file
```

If you want to have just in one line

```
echo -n "text" >> file
date >> file
```

Comment: How can I append line breaks? Is there a way that I can pull this off with just one line of commands?

Comment: @jon-doe You can append line breaks by using `echo` - by default, it sends a line break; if you want more, you would do (for adding 4 line breaks) `echo -e '\n\n\n'`. To do it in one line, you can use braces `{ echo "text"; echo date; } >> file`.

Comment: Adding curly braces didn't work for me. But adding parenthesis worked out. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. This is what I used - `(echo -n "test : "; date;) >> file.log`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `printf` instead. A one line solution would be

> `printf "\nsome text\n$(date)" >> file.txt`